# How to generate nonce for woocomerce in node js

Tags: node.js, woocommerce

I am developing a woocommerce project. I need to call the store apis of woocommerce for managing the cart. I need to pass the nonce in the header. I need to know how to generate nonce in node js backend or is their any other alternative to access the store apis. Please help me I am stuck in this. I am unable to find any solution for this